# Opencart basics - Is it possible to write a custom controller to use in a view or do I have to use modules?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I am working on a theme for [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) and am finding I need access to different variables than provided by the default controllers.

For example, in the Category view, I would like to access the full product image rather than the thumbnail which is what the controller provides by default.

Coming from Wordpress, I would be used to simply calling a function to retrieve a different image size, but I assume that in MVC, this functionality needs to be in the controller.

However, I see no way to write a custom controller and editing the original means huge problems when updating.

As a very basic fundamental question, is the only solution to write a Module? Is this the proper practice when developing a theme for opencart? Somehow, I have not found a very definitive clear explanation of how I am supposed to work with opencart themes (a la wordpress codex).

Comment: Another good place to look also `OPENCART ROOT > SYSTEM LIBRARY > ` and then choose a file example, customer.php, you can see all the echo and declarations and how to call many variables in and around the Opencart environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't need to be done in the controller at all, the view can access just as much information as the controller can. You just need to use this in the product loop

```
$prod = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
$full_image = empty($prod['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $prod['image'];
```

Note however that you should resize the image from there using the resize method of the tool/image model to the dimensions you want for consistency

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you so much! I ended up working on a custom module which is doing what I need and in the process I figured out a bit more, and this solution you provided me with works perfectly. *Just out of curiosity though*, using this code in the 'view' is technically a break of the MVC convention though, no?

Comment: It is, but then there are worse things you could do, and the end goal is to get it to work as you want it. You could have used a vQmod to add the original image to the product array instead, which wouldn't have broken MVC, then used that instead

Comment: Ok, just checking – I'm still a beginner with MVC, so trying to make sure my assumptions are correct. Also am looking into vQmod, but that is definitely a task in itself! Many thanks.

Comment: vqmod is actually very simple. It's basically a search and replace system in effect, with a few extra features for greater accuracy